# Scala object onload

Tags: scala, object, design-patterns, factory

I want to implement a factory. There have to be only one instance of this factory in my app. My factory needs to do some preparation before it creates the first MyObject, and only then. Is there any better way to do it than

```
object MyObjectFactory {
    private var isApplied:Boolean = false
    def apply() = {
        if(!isApplied) {
            isApplied = true;
            onLoad
        }
        //do something
        new MyObject
    }
    def onLoad {
        //prepare environment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`object`s are created lazily, so you can just put the onLoad logic into the constructor. It will be executed the first time it is used, not just imported.

```
scala> object Factory {
     |   onLoad()
     |   def apply() = "new object"
     |   def onLoad() = println("onload")
     | }
defined object Factory
// no onLoad triggered yet

scala> Factory()
onload
res0: String = new object
// onLoad was triggered

scala> Factory()
res1: String = new object
// onLoad was not triggered
```